# How to update Datagrid using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have searched and have come to a brick wall. There seems to be plenty of questions and answers on how to do this, but I can't find anything specifically that I can implement(Obviously an issue with my understanding).

I was hoping to be able to update several Datagrids and going off the premise that you should not be naming you controls, I am lost as to how to get this to work.

So what I have been able to come up with thus far is using the `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly. But I have no Idea how to implement the code behind (I certainly could show all the code I have tried to get it to work, but unfortunately it would just clutter the post, so I am not including it). I have research as much as I can on implementing `ICommand`.

So I have the XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CanExecuteChanged}" />
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But I can't seem to get the code behind to be able to notify when the `RowEditEnding` has finished and be able to update the database with the new data.

So with the MVVM model in mind, how do I go about getting an event to fire so I can update the database?

Comment: You should post your whole view code and code behind if you want proper help... what class are you showing in your datagrid? etc.

Comment: When working with MVVM you need to understand the concept so it's best to patiently and carefuly read tutorial as such: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid ...good luck

Comment: @ChenChi, I have already downloaded that project and tried to implement the principles that it shows , with no success.

Comment: Why would you use RowEditing? If you are using mvvm you should use your viewmodel change notification, not UI control events.

Comment: Sorry, that's too big for an SO question. SO Documentation may have something, if not request it there. I'll see if I can find a concise example of change notification on collection items.

Comment: This forum likes to see a [complete, minimal and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least show your ViewModel and supporting classes but pare them down to only the necessary bits.

Comment: @KyloRen "why would I use an event tied to the view when I am trying to implement MVVM?KayloRen" - the whole point is to have empty codebehind of the view that way it's seperation of conerns.

Comment: @ChenChi, After seeing the answer to this question, I understand what you were trying to say. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT2: Changed People to an ObservableCollection instead of List.  Added CollectionChanged event to handle attaching/removing PropertyChanged events from Person objects in the collection.

EDIT: changed foreach in ViewModel for consistency.

First, Model-View-ViewModel(MVVM) means that you should have as little code behind as possible, preferably none in fact.  Instead, logic for the UI should be done in xaml (the View), while logic for the data should be done in the Model and the organization of the data into presentable form should be done via the View Model, which is a separate file that knows nothing about WPF or the UI.

It also seems you have a misunderstanding as to how data binding works. You are referring to stuff you have done in code behind, but binding expressions usually point to a property on your view's `DataContext`, which in MVVM should be set to your ViewModel.  There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/hello-bound-world/) that can get you started with binding.  I also recommend the followup posts to that one, they helped me a great deal when I was starting out WPF.

Now for the situation with the DataGrid.  First, [here](https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) is a good tutorial on the WPF DataGrid.
Next, you state that you want to update the database when the row has been updated.  Here is an example of how to do that in MVVM style:

Suppose you have a view with a DataGrid like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People, Mode=OneWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace TestWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the code behind is almost empty.  Just the default code, plus `DataContext = new MyViewModel();`.  As I mentioned earlier, the DataContext of your view should be your View Model.

`MyViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Impl
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<Person> m_people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return m_people; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == m_people)
                return;

            m_people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        m_people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        m_people.CollectionChanged += m_people_CollectionChanged;
        m_people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Brown", Age = 45 });
        m_people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Sarah", LastName = "Smith", Age = 25 });
    }

    private void m_people_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += people_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= people_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    //Property Changed will be called whenever a property of one of the 'Person'
    //objects is changed.
    private void person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = sender as Person;
        SaveData(row);
    }

    private void SaveData(Person row)
    {
        //Save the row to the database here.
    }
}
```

I have a property of type `List<Person>` in my view model.  `Person` looks like this:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Impl
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    private string m_firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return m_firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == m_firstName)
                return;

            m_firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string m_lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return m_lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == m_lastName)
                return;

            m_lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int m_age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return m_age; }
        set
        {
            if (value == m_age)
                return;

            m_age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to note here is **INotifyPropertyChanged**, this interface is very important to MVVM and WPF data binding in general.  When implemented properly, it causes an object to publish a `PropertyChanged` event whenever one of its properties is changed.  This tells any bound WPF controls that they should get the new value, and also allows your ViewModel to watch them for changes. So in the view model, we attach an event handler to the `CollectionChanged` event on People, which then takes care of attaching the `PropertyChanged` event handler for each item added to the collection.

The `CollectionChanged` event will be called whenever an item is added, removed, or replaced in the collection and will remove the `PropertyChanged` handler from the old items and add the handler to the new ones.  It is important to remember to remove the handlers, or items removed from the collection may not be properly garbage collected.

The `person_PropertyChanged` method will be called each time a property of one of the `Person` objects changes.  In `person_PropertyChanged` we then call the methods to update the database, passing the updated row (Person in this case), like below:

```
//Property Changed will be called whenever a property of one of the 'Person'
//objects is changed.
private void person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = sender as Person;
    SaveData(row);
}

private void SaveData(Person row)
{
    //Save the row to the database here.
}
```

Each row in the grid I displayed above represents one person object.  Whenever the user changes a value of one of the cells in the grid, the corresponding property of the `Person` object that the row represents will be updated as well, which will trigger a `PropertyChanged` event, and call `person_PropertyChanged`.

Suppose the user changes the `Age` column of "Bob" to 37.  After the user hits enter or moves off the cell for `Age` the Age property of the `Person` object representing "Bob" will be changed to 37 from 45.  This will cause that `Person` object to raise `PropertyChanged`, which will call the `person_PropertyChanged` method in `MyViewModel`.  `person_PropertyChanged` will then call `SaveData` which is where you would put the code to save the updated Person row to the database.

If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: I would give you 10 upvotes for this answer , but I can only give one. Forgive my lack of knowledge of terms, but when I say code behind, I meant in the `ViewModel`. I understand how `INotifyPropertyChanged` works , but what I could not not wrap my head around was how to save stuff to the DB. Q1: I am using Enity Framework as the model, how would this differ from your answer?  Q2: Once the  `PropertyChangedEventArgs ` fires, I am gathering I can do anything that needs to be done in the Database from there?

Comment: How are you looping through the type `People` ? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @KyloRen People is a property of type List<Person>, not a type.  Not sure why stack overflow's code formatting thinks its a type.

Comment: @KyloRen That depends on a bunch of different stuff.  It really should be its own question.  Here is a starter guide that may help you understand: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Comment: @KyloRen If you do make your own question, make sure to clarify what version of EntityFramework you are using, as well as whether your database is Code First or Database First.

Comment: No , my mistake, I saw the class `Person` and assumed that is what you were referring to. You are using a list to subcribe the `propertyChanged` even, I imagine it is the same for an Observable collection?

Comment: From what I understand it is Model first.

Comment: Yes pretty much, you only subscribe to the observable collection itself, rather than to each element.  It probably would have been better to make People an ObservableCollection<Person> then List<Person>, since observable colllection means you don't have to make sure you subscribe to each new element.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean there. Do you mean you will not have to loop through each element of the `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136753/discussion-between-brandon-kramer-and-kyloren).

Comment: Many thanks for both the question and the answer. @BrandonKramer How do we know which action to do in SaveData function (Add/Update/Delete into db)?